# Image processing server

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation

I'm looking for a free, preferably open source, http [image processing server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_server). I.e. I would send it a request like this:

```
http://myimageserver/rotate?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2FContent%2FImg%2Fstackoverflow-logo-250.png&angle=90
```

and it would return that image rotated. Features wanted:

- Server-side caching
- Several operations/effects (like scaling, watermarking, etc). The more the merrier.
- POST support to supply the image (instead of the server GETting it).
- Different output formats (PNG, JPEG, etc).
- Batch operations

It would be something like [this](http://leadtools.com/SDK/web-services/Image-Service/default.htm), but free and less SOAPy. Is there anything like this or am I asking too much?

Comment: Sounds like [imageresizing.net](http://imageresizing.net). It's open-source, supports a very human-readable URL syntax, offers server-side disk caching, scaling, watermarking, cropping, rotation, PNG/Jpeg/GIF output, and can do batch operations. It doesn't currently support POST, but that could be easily added as a plugin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [ImageResizing.Net library](http://imageresizing.net) is both a .NET library and an IIS module. It's an image server or an image library, whichever you prefer.

It's open-source, under an [MIT-style license](http://imageresizing.net/licenses/), and is supported by plugins.

It has excellent performance, and supports 3 pipelines: GDI+, Windows Imaging Components, and FreeImage. WIC is the fastest, and can do some operations in under 15ms.  It supports disk caching (for up to 1 million files), and is CDN compatible (Amazon CloudFront is ideal).

It has a very human-friendly URL syntax. Ex. `image.jpg?width=100&height=100&mode=crop`.

It supports resizing, cropping, padding, rotation, PNG/GIF/JPG output, borders, watermarking, remote URLs, Amazon S3, MS SQL, Amazon CloudFront, batch operations, image filters, disk caching, and lots of other cool stuff, like seam carving.

It doesn't support POST delivery of images, but that's easy to do with a plugin. And don't you typically want to store images that are delivered via POST instead of just replying to the POST command with the result?

[Disclosure: I'm the author of ImageResizer]

Comment: Also, Imageflow runs natively on Linux, OS X, and Windows. https://github.com/imazen/imageflow

Answer (score 4):

Apache::ImageMagick, you install that - and also Apache along with mod_perl. This is the standard setup, check docs, there are alternatives. This is probably as turn-key as it gets.

Sample conf:

```
<Location /img>
PerlFixupHandler Apache::ImageMagick
PerlSetVar AIMCacheDir /tmp/your/cache/directory
</Location>
```

Your requests could look like:
http://domain/img/test.gif/Frame?color=red

More docs are [here](http://search.cpan.org/~grichter/Apache-ImageMagick-2.0b7/ImageMagick.pm)!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LibGD](http://libgd.org) or [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to build a service like that fairly easily. They both have many language bindings.

Answer (score 2):

While not an out of the box solution, check out [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).  There is a perl [interface](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php) for it, so combine that with some fairly simple cgi scripts, or mod_perl and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You could make this with Google App Engine -- they provide image processing routines and will host for free within some bounds.

Here are some examples of people doing things like this already

http://appgallery.appspot.com/results?q=image

Answer (score 1):

I found [this product](http://www.aspjpeg.com/), it seems to match my requirements

Answer (score 1):

Try [Nginx image processing server with OpenResty and Lua](http://leafo.net/posts/creating_an_image_server.html). It uses ImageMagick C API. Openresty comes with [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org/). It has amazing performance in terms of speed. Checkout some benchmarks for LuaJIT and Openresty.